# Suggestions for conditionally loading image A or image B

Tags: conditionals, includegraphics

I have a latex color definition file (that I switch out with `\input`) to produced a "themed" PDF for green, tan, and blue (works well with some Python code).  The final step is to conditionally load the green, tan, or blue variation I have for certain graphics.

Being somewhat new to LaTeX, I'm looking for suggestions to set up `\includegraphics` for loading the blue, tan, or green versions of those images throughout the document - depending on the theme color. Does LaTeX support an if then construct for loading images?

Or would I do better to move the themed images into my master "Images" directory with python code run just before LaTeX compiling?

Comment: This is definitely possible. How do you currently switch between the themes from within your (La)TeX document? Do you `\input` a different file based on the theme?

Comment: Yes.  I use “shadecolor”, for example,  in latex code.   But that color is defined differently in green, tan, or blue colordefinitions.Tex file that is swapped out with \input.  That handles text colors and highlighting and such.  I just need to set up the final piece to load the correct graphics that matches the theme

Comment: What you should do is add conditionals to your `\input` file of the following form: `\newcommand{\themecolor}{blue}` which you can then later test against using `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{blue}{\themecolor}=0 <blue theme stuff> \fi`, or other comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like

```
\newcommand{\setthemecolor}[1]{\expandafter\def\csname theme#1\endcsname{}}

\setthemecolor{blue}
```

to part of the file that you input, so you explicitly specify the theme colour as being `blue`, `green` or `tan`. By setting the theme colour, `\setthemecolor` creates either a macro `\themeblue`, `\themegreen` or `\themetan`. You can then check which of these macros exist later in your document via `\ifcsname <macro>\endcsname <stuff> \fi`.

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\setthemecolor}[1]{\expandafter\def\csname theme#1\endcsname{}}

\setthemecolor{blue}

\begin{document}

This is the start of the document.

\ifcsname themeblue\endcsname
  This is only in a blue document.
\fi

\ifcsname themegreen\endcsname
  This is only in a green document.
\fi

\ifcsname themetan\endcsname
  This is only in a tan document.
\fi

This is the end of the document.

\end{document}
```

---

An alternative would be to name the images based on the colour of your theme. For example, `imageblue.pdf`, `imagegreen.pdf` and `imagetan.pdf`. This way you can just insert

```
\newcommand{\themecolor}{blue}
```

in the file you `\input` and use

```
\includegraphics[<opt>]{image\themecolor}
```

wherever you want to input a theme-specific image.

Comment: Perfect.   Nice.   Thanks.

Comment: Yet another alternative is to use the same image file names for every theme, but to load a different graphics file path in the \input file (or have one path for un-themed graphics and a theme path as well). \graphicspath{{imagestemplate/}{images/}}%several subfolders & root

Comment: I have tested all three of your suggested methods.  they all work fine ... I like option 2 best.  I'm using image_name_green.jpg and using  \includegraphics[<opts>]{image_name_\themecolor}   Fantastic !!    (for readability, I think you meant to have `imageblue.png` above as opposed to `imageblue.pdf` ... but I got the message.